# How to sort a core data entity on basis of date key

Tags: entity-framework, sorting, date, core-data, nsdate

I have an entity in Core Data called Info and an attribute called 'date' which is of type string. I want to be able to sort the entity by means of the date, in a suitable date format. Currently the 'date' is a string of format 'mm/dd/yy'. How do I format the string suitably and perform the sorting.

This is my present code snippet:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest1 = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Info"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest1 setSortDescriptors:@[sort]];

    NSError *error0 =nil;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest1 error:&error0];
    fetchedObjects2 = results;
    [fetchRequest1 setFetchBatchSize:20];

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
        _fetchedResultsController = nil;
    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest1
                                        managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

This is displayed in a table.

```
- (void)reloadTableViewData
{
    NSError *error;

    if (![[self fetchedResultsController0] performFetch:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }

    [TableView reloadData];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

This is the entity:

[image: 'Info' Entity]

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should store your data in a way that allows for easy data manipulation.  You can always massage it for any presentation effects you desire.

If you really want to keep the date stored as mm/dd/yy, you should also store another item, something like sortableDate, which is in a numeric representation or in a string format as yyyymmdd.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no justification to storing a date in anything else but an `NSDate`. Refactor to use a proper date object and sorting will be a breeze.

If you need your string, use a date formatter.

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy"
let stringRepresentation = formatter.stringFromDate(dateObject)
```

(Note that this just demonstrates how to get your specific string. Actually, you should provide proper date strings for different locales, i.e., not hard-code the `dateFormat`.)